# Standard Matrices for Linear Transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm not able to find an explanation for finding the standard matrix for a linear transformation of equations. For example, if I have;

$$w_1=2x_1-3x_2+x_4$$

$$w_2=3x_1+5x_2-x_4$$

Would the standard matrix just be:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
2 & -3 & 0 & 1 \\
3 & 5 & 0 & -1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: That is right. If you multiply your matrix  with $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)^T$ you get $(w_1,w_2)^T$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the standard matrix of a linear trasformation $T$ from $\mathbb{R}^{n}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{m}$ one need to consider what $T$ does to the columns of $n\times n$ identity matrix, $I_n$. Because any vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$ can be obtained by scaling the columns of $I_n$ matrix.

So you should substitute $x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4 $ with the columns of $I_n$ which will give you the elements of the standard matrix.
Please have a look here http://dip.sun.ac.za/~hanno/twb264/lesings/matrix_lin_trans.pdf for more information.
Your answer is correct.